# I have a list of 2 dimensional arrays. How to convert the list into a 3 dimensional numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

L is a list of 1000 arrays of size (300,300).
So I have to convert L into a numpy array(3D) of size (300,300)x 1000.

Comment: Use numpy.expand_dims()

Comment: Sounds like you just want `np.stack(L, axis=-1)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `np.stack`. It requires a sequence (you have a list which will work) of arrays to stack along a new axis. Note that `axis=-1` gives you the axis specification you have asked for.

```
# list of arrays made of random noise
x_list = [np.random.normal(0.0, 1.0, size=(300, 300)) for _ in range(1000)]
# array made of arrays in list
x_array = np.stack(x_list, axis=-1)

print("Shape of array: ", x_array.shape)
```

This gives

```
>>> Shape of array: (300, 300, 1000)
```